# What are the dimensions of a Continental coin?

Tags: props, john-wick

I've been looking online for authentic reproductions of the currency used in the John Wick universe.

Everywhere I look, the diameter offered is either 34 or 40 mm.  That seems too small.  The coins in the movies looked to be closer to 3" in diameter.

Is there an authoritative source on the dimensions of these props?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the website [APMEX](https://www.apmex.com/product/193803/john-wick-1-oz-gold-continental-coin), the company partnered with Lionsgate to produce an exact replica of the Continental coin.

> APMEX has partnered with Lionsgate to produce this exclusive, limited
> mintage series based on the currency featured in the John Wick saga.
> This 1 oz .9999 fine Gold round comes with a mirrored finish at a
> great price point!
>
> Diameter:  34 mm

**According to the AMPEX website, the diameter is 34 mm**

This photo shows a 34 mm wrist watch with a hand holding it for size comparison:
[image]

This photo shows a scene from the movie where John Wick is picking up the coins:

[image]

They appear to be the same size

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why I thought they were bigger.  Now all I need is $2,000 of disposable income for one of these.

Comment: I thought they looked bigger, then in subsequent films they got smaller. I posted my theory why, but i dont have more info to go on; in jw1 it **seemed** bigger

Comment: @blobbymcblobby Why did you delete your answer?  It was a good answer

Comment: @steelersquirrel i thought it was probably wrong lol

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an answer but something to consider:

[image]

*Average US male hand is 7.6" across, and their hands are not flat out, so coin is looking roughly 2.2" here, whilst the JW3 coins widely available look a little small ...*

Based on that, the coin looks bigger than 1.5", more than 2" if i compared it to my "tiny tim" digits.

Yet, most of the prop coins used that I can easily find are from JW3, and all their coins are 1.5" as @steelersquirrel also found.

Usually a good source, aside from props (persons) themselves, are prop auction houses, such as:

https://propstore.com/product/john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum/pair-of-high-table-currency-coins/

[image]

- and they also included plastic stunt coins, and rolls of same said coins, all have the same 1.5" dimensions.

I did notice this when i watched the films, it *seemed* the coins got smaller. (note: personal perception)

From this I will only say that generally decisions get made at the time of the production that sometimes get lost in time.

So, originally the coin was possibly larger, to make it more..distinctive as this mysterious currency, and then subsequently, long after it was established, they settled on something approaching a more portable (or standardized) size for the rest of the franchise series.

So ultimately, *if there was a size change*, I think its a production/art direction issue that made the size change...

One thing I came across is that *(if)* the coins in first film varied in size as a prop, due to art direction, and then when it came to actually producing more of them later (and for the sequels), they could well have reverted to a "Troy ounce" coin (system of weights used for precious metals and gems) standard in weight and size, which in the US this is a Morgan Silver Dollar, weighing a standard 31gr and are 1.5" across.

Comment: There's definitely a good answer in here, but you've gone all around the houses trying to explain it.

Comment: @Valorum i wasn't sure it was an answer at all as I couldn't find anything conclusive, which is why I originally deleted it... But the OP's question made me remember that I did think the coins got smaller at the time, I just don't have proof./ Or it was just in my (and OP's) head... (I made it an 'answer' because it couldn't fit in the comments..)

Comment: I'd ditch the pictures and go with the prop, perhaps. That's quite an interesting find

Comment: Agreed.  I thought that it was an interesting answer with a lot of good facts